# Python socket server login system not working

Tags: python, sockets

I am coding a python socket server that when you connect you login with a username and password separated with ":" whenever you say something in the connected server it will send the message to everyone else using function "Broadcast()"

But when I try logging in it doesn't say "Welcome" which is what it should say. It just doesn't do anything, it fails to login basically.

I am using PuTTY to connect to it.

Code:

```
import socket
import threading
from thread import start_new_thread

connect = ""
conport = 8080

clients = []

def client_thread(conn):
    fd = open("login.txt", "r")

    def username(conn, prefix="Username: "):
        conn.send(prefix)
        return conn.recv(2048)

    def password(conn, prefix="Password: "):
        conn.send(prefix)
        return conn.recv(2048)

    username = username(conn)
    password = password(conn)

    for line in fd:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.split(":")[0] in username and line.split(":")[1] in password:
            while True:
                conn.send("Welcome")
                message = conn.recv(2048)

                print(message)

                if message:
                    broadcast(message, conn)
                else:
                    remove(conn)

                if not message:
                    break

def start_client():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((connect, conport))
    sock.listen(1)
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        clients.append(conn)

        start_new_thread(client_thread, (conn,))

    sock.close()

def broadcast(message, connection):
    for machine in clients:
        if machine != connection:
            try:
                machine.sendall(message)
            except:
                machine.close()
                remove(machine)

def remove(connection):
    if connection in clients:
        clients.remove(connection)

threading.Thread(target=start_client).start()
```

Expected Outcome:

```
Username: Admin
Password: 1234
Welcome
```

Actual Outcome:

```
Username: Admin
Password: 1234
```

login.txt

```
Admin:1234
Nimda:4321
```

Can you please help me? It won't login correctly :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has lots of issues.

You hide your local functions `username` and `password` with variables, having same names.

You dont close your `fd` (consider using `with` statement)

Your logic looks like first thing client should see is `Username:`, not `Welcome`.

You are most likely confusing `str` and `bytes` in your code.

Following code works on **Python3**, but still is extremely erroneous:

```
import socket
import threading
from _thread import start_new_thread

connect = ""
conport = 8080

clients = []


def receive(conn, prefix):
    conn.send(prefix)
    data = b''

    while b'\n' not in data:
        portion = conn.recv(1024)
        if portion:
            data += portion

    return data.decode('utf-8').strip()


def client_thread(conn):
    with open("login.txt", "r") as fd:
        username = receive(conn, b'Username: ')
        password = receive(conn, b'Password: ')

        for line in fd:
            u, p = line.strip().split(':')
            if u == username and p == password:
                while True:
                    conn.send(b'Welcome')
                    message = conn.recv(2048)
                    if message:
                        broadcast(message, conn)
                    else:
                        remove(conn)
                    if not message:
                        break


def start_client():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((connect, conport))
    sock.listen(1)
    try:
        while True:
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            clients.append(conn)
            start_new_thread(client_thread, (conn,))
    finally:
        sock.close()


def broadcast(message, connection):
    for machine in clients:
        if machine != connection:
            try:
                machine.sendall(message)
            except:
                machine.close()
                remove(machine)


def remove(connection):
    if connection in clients:
        clients.remove(connection)

threading.Thread(target=start_client).start()
```

Comment: I don't get any errors or issues when I run it. What server logs are you referring to? The code doesn't throw back any errors.

Comment: Do you get `Username` invitation on client? Try sending bytes instead of strings. E.g. `def username(conn, prefix=b"Username: "):` - notice prefix `b`

Comment: No like, I get the message saying "Username" and "Password" but when I input the credentials it just does nothing
Username: Admin
Password: 1234

See. Nothing happens

Comment: Here, I edited my question for what the outcome should be, and what the outcome actually is

Comment: Updated an answer. Guess the problem is in comparison of `bytes` and `str`, which is always False

Comment: Even when I do this, it will not log me in :/

Comment: Can you post your `login.txt` file

Comment: I am sure, the problem is in `if line.split(":")[0] in username and line.split(":")[1] in password:`. Put `print('Line="%s", Username="%s", Pwd="%s"' % (line, username, password))` before and see the logs.

Comment: Line="Admin:1234", Username="Admin", Pwd="
"

Comment: It for some reason didn't receive the password, why?

Comment: So, you have problems sending the password. Looks like on client side you send it byte by byte instead of sending in one package.

Comment: Best idea - to use ready frameworks, like `twisted` or others. In `twisted` you just have to implement something like `LineReceiver`. If you want to do it from scratch, you have to implement **accumulating** algorithm on server side, to read input until you get line feed, for example.

Comment: There is, but anyway this program is very erroneous. Rewrite your receive code to accumulate input data. Something like this: `rcv = b"" while '\n' not in rcv: rcv += conn.recv(...)    return rcv.decode('utf-8').strip()`

Comment: I just used your receive code, same result: Line="Admin:1234", Username="Admin", Pwd=""

Comment: I am sorry to say this, but I still get the same result even with this update. Just to inform you in case you were unaware, I am using python 2.7.10

Comment: Okay, I've rewritten a bit your code and tested it on my machine - it works for me now.  You have to replace `from _thread import start_new_thread` by `from thread import start_new_thread` to make it Python 2.7. I have only Python3 and I tested on it.

Comment: As a test client, I used `nc 127.0.0.1 8080`. But it is only linux, until you find `netcat` for Windows

Comment: 1 sec, let me login into my VPS to test it again

Comment: I am still getting the same issue when I use PuTTY to login

Comment: You are using `Raw` connection type?

Comment: Seems like your client does not append `\n` at the end of the message.

Comment: I assume Putty, being a Windows program, appends `\r\n`. Try changing `.strip()` to `.strip(' \t\r\n')`

Comment: Still nothing :/

Comment: It **works** with Putty, if you chose `Raw` connection type and modify `return data.decode('utf-8').strip('\r\n\t ')` Just tested